# saned.socket vs saned

Tags: networking, systemd, services, scanner, sane

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 and I've successfully managed to configure an Epson network scanner in my LAN using *sane* utility.
Although the scanner works fine, command `sudo systemctl status saned` shows the following

```
    ● saned.service - LSB: SANE network scanner server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/saned; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-03-04 09:47:47 CET; 1min 5s
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1166 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/saned start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1166]:  * Starting SANE network scanner server sa
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1180]: saned (AF-indep+IPv6) from sane-backends 1
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1180]: do_bindings: [1] bind failed: Address alre
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1180]: do_bindings: [0] bind failed: Address alre
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1180]: do_bindings: couldn't bind an address. Exi
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1180]: FATAL ERROR; bailing out, waiting for chil
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC saned[1180]: bail_out: all children exited
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC systemd[1]: saned.service: Control process exited, code
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC systemd[1]: saned.service: Failed with result 'exit-cod
Mar 04 09:47:47 david-PC systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: SANE network scanner s
```

Trying to figure out what's going wrong with sane, I run `sudo netstat -tlnp` which shows the following:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1579            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1234/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1009/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1067/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1080/ecbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::6566                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::1579                 :::*                    LISTEN      1234/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1067/cupsd
```

I don't understand why process *init* is using port 6566, which should be occupied by sane server.
Here is the point: command `systemctl -all list-sockets` shows that port 6566 is used by *saned.socket*

```
LISTEN                       UNIT                            ACTIVATES
/run/acpid.socket            acpid.socket                    acpid.service
/run/apport.socket           apport-forward.socket          
/run/avahi-daemon/socket     avahi-daemon.socket             avahi-daemon.service
/run/cups/cups.sock          cups.socket                     cups.service
/run/dbus/system_bus_socket  dbus.socket                     dbus.service
/run/initctl                 systemd-initctl.socket          systemd-initctl.service
/run/snapd-snap.socket       snapd.socket                    snapd.service
/run/snapd.socket            snapd.socket                    snapd.service
/run/systemd/fsck.progress   systemd-fsckd.socket            systemd-fsckd.service
/run/systemd/journal/dev-log systemd-journald-dev-log.socket systemd-journald.service
/run/systemd/journal/socket  systemd-journald.socket         systemd-journald.service
/run/systemd/journal/stdout  systemd-journald.socket         systemd-journald.service
/run/systemd/journal/syslog  syslog.socket                   rsyslog.service
/run/udev/control            systemd-udevd-control.socket    systemd-udevd.service
/run/uuidd/request           uuidd.socket                    uuidd.service
[::]:6566                    saned.socket                    saned@0-192.168.1.66:6566-192.168.1.66:36282
audit 1                      systemd-journald-audit.socket   systemd-journald.service
kobject-uevent 1             systemd-udevd-kernel.socket     systemd-udevd.service
```

Of course, if I stop *saned.socket* and then start *saned*, the parts do the opposite, so *saned.socket* goes down and *saned* goes up.
I'm not an expert of Unix systems, so I want to understand which is the difference between `saned.socket` and `saned` and find out a way to get both them working properly